# Steam/Ubuntu help - broken packages/unmet dependencies - can't upgrade

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I've posted the same thing in Ubuntu Forums and Steam community but not found a solution.

`sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` leads to the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
steam:i386 : Conflicts: steam-launcher but 1:1.0.0.64 is to be installed
Conflicts: steam-launcher:i386
steam-devices : Conflicts: steam-launcher but 1:1.0.0.64 is to be installed
Conflicts: steam-launcher:i386
E: Broken packages
```

---

I don't know if there's any connection between the two, but software updater works perfectly fine.

Steam also updates upon launch as per usual.

When I run `sudo apt update` I'm told there are 22 packages with requiring upgrades so I'm hopeful of finding a fix.

I've also run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

But nothing happened.

Thanks in advance.

*Version info - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Steam API: v020 Package versions: 1591251555

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. I wonder if you had any luck since you posted this question? Is it possible, that our ubuntu config doesn't allow the installation of i386 tagged packages?

Comment: Yes. This question appears to have been edited to include solutions to similar questions. I can't remember which one it was but if you go through the links attached above, one of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should update your repository and fix unmet dependencies. Open terminal and run:

```bsh
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Replace the old repository with the new one and save the file. Then run:

```bsh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
```

Lay more emphasis on your repository. Good luck!

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thanks for sharing!